# Change CSS Style with jquery in following HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, aspmenu-control

I am working on one of the asp.net project which uses Drop-down Menus from from [Dynamic Drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm)

After using it with asp.net Menu control asp.net automatically adds styles to it. I want to replace part of `CSS Style` using jQuery from the following code. I would appreciate  help in this regards.

```
<li class="" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:11" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left; z-index: 100;">
<a href="#?PageId=49&amp;Language=en-US" class="popout level1 static" tabindex="-1" style="padding-right: 10px;">MAIN MENU<img style="border:0;" class="downarrowclass1" src="../down.gif"></a>
    <ul class="" id="Menu1:submenu:11" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 186px;">
        <li role="menuitem" class="" style="position: relative;">
            <a href="#?PageId=50&amp;Language=en-US&amp;" class="level2 dynamic" tabindex="-1">SUB MENU</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="" style="position: relative;">
            <a href="#?PageId=52&amp;Language=en-US&amp;" class="level2 dynamic" tabindex="-1">SUB MENU/a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem" class="" style="position: relative;">
            <a href="#?PageId=51&amp;Language=en-US&amp;" class="level2 dynamic" tabindex="-1">SUB MENU</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to change the style value of `top: 28px;` in  `UL` with `id="Menu1:submenu:11"` to `top:-58px`; I am not sure how I can do.

HTML code is exact copy of asp.net web form in the browse.

I am not sure how I can reference to element with id `Menu1:submenu:11` using jQuery & over right the whole style property `style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 186px;"`

Answer (score 0):

All style changes are easy once you know how:

```
 $('#Menu1:submenu:11').css('top':-58);
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for a lot more details

**edit**

I just saw that your problem is that you can't access the selector: `$('#Menu1:submenu:11')`? I suggest submitting another question or searching a little more to find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Menu1:submenu:11').style.top = "-58px";
```

Comment: @Jamie Hutber why cant he access the element?

Comment: I am not able to change it with any of the answer actual website address is look for Menu ISLAM link http://tinyurl.com/d3dlwf2

Comment: on actual website i want menu to pull up rather than pull down